# Setting a variable type with ":URL" causes error

Tags: typescript

I created "test.ts" in VSCode like this:

```
var data ="https://a.b.c/d/e/f";
var url = new URL(data);
console.log(url.protocol);
```

and when I press F5 outputs "https:". But If I add the type like

```
var url:URL = new URL(data);
```

and press F5, the output is:

```
Process exited with code 1
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\test.ts
Uncaught c:\[path]\test.ts:2
var url:URL = new URL(data);
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
```

What is wrong? If I search for the syntax, I can see an example like:

[image]

Comment: Node does not understand typescript syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run your typescript code with node, you need to transpile it to Javascript. you can use `tsc` to do this and then run the transpiled javascript code using node.

Or you can use `ts-node` to run the typescript file directly. you can use `npm install ts-node` to install. This is a less efficient method and I don't recommend it for production runtime.